# Difference between DC polarity symbols

Tags: dc, symbol

On some devices, the DC polarity symbol uses diamonds or squares for the poles instead of circles. Do these two styles represent any electrical of mechanical difference, or is it purely cosmetic?

[image: dc polarity with diamonds]
[image: dc polarity with circles]

Comment: afaik no, but I'm sure an expert will come along soon

Comment: it is a schematic diagram ... physical properties are not usually shown in schematics

Comment: Is this really a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose is always to see the polarity of the output pins, everything else is just visual taste.